# Vscode keeps moving my commented lines on save

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

Everytime I save my python project, it keeps moving my comments away from my flask routes by two lines.

I disabled prettier
I disabled intelisense
I also restarted vscode

But the issue still remains:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can provide your setting.json and extension installed. I haven't meet this problem on my vscode when I reproduced your use. If you modify the following code, will you still encounter this problem?     "editor.formatOnSave": true, change "true" to "false"

Comment: Your suggestion did the trick. Changing the `formateOnSave` from On to Off (false) worked out perfectly. I am sorry as I am a pleb noob who doesn't know how to use the settings.json file correctly for vscode. (even though I know json structures very well). So I just went to the settings options graphically and copy and pasted what you wrote `editor.formatOnSave` and it showed me the option you were talking about. I changed it to false and then tried again and it worked. If you want to make an answer I will give you credit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ctrl+p and type "setting.json".
2. Find the line named "editor.formatOnSave", change "true" to "false"

Comment: Update: If you still want to use formatOnSave, you can change your can search "python formatting provider" in your settings and change "autopep8" to "black".